# Hierarchical Select Doesn't allow multiple vocabularies in drupal7

Tags: entities

Hierarchical Select I have taxonomy vocabularies:

For example

Products, systems and Support

Each vocabulary has 2 terms:

Products -> product1, product2

systems -> systems 1, systems 2

Support -> support1, support2

I am using Hierarchical Select as a field to select this vocabularies.

But with Hierarchical Select ,it is defaulting to only one vocabulary.

Please let me know how to select terms from multiple vocabularies while creating nodes and alternate to Hierarchical Select.

Answer (score 1):

You can't I'm afraid; it's actually a limitation of the taxonomy term field type, not of Hierarchical Select.

You can only ever choose one vocabulary per term reference field, regardless of the widget you're using. For example, this is what the field settings page looks like when adding a bog standard term ref field on a Drupal install that doesn't even have HS installed:

[image]

As you can see you only have the option to choose one vocabulary.

Comment: Could you please suggest any field to attach multiple vocabularies to a content type.Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a sandbox module called [Vocabulary reference](http://drupal.org/project/vocabulary_reference) but it only has a select list as widget, it won't work with HS. Since HS is hard-coded to use the term reference field I don't think you'll find a multi-vocab field type that it works on to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Try using entity reference instead of term reference as your field type. Here's how I got it to work for my needs.  In Field Settings I chose Target Type: Taxonomy Term; Entity Selection: Mode: Simple (with optional filter by bundle).  This will show a list of all vocabularies with check boxes next to each (Target Bundles).  Select the vocabularies you would like to be able to reference.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The drupal core taxonomy module is actually coded in a way that allows for multiple vocabs on a term reference field, however it is not exposed to the user via the field UI.

There is a module [Combined Termref](https://drupal.org/project/combined_termref) that exposes this ability.

The drawback it currently has is it is hard coded to allow up to 3 vocabs, not unlimited, although I plan to write a patch for unlimited as I will need that ability soon.

There is also a related drupal core issue at https://drupal.org/node/1623054 that has been closed in favour of https://drupal.org/node/1801304, which has removed term reference fields in favour of entity reference fields, so you should be able to reference multiple vocabs in drupal 8 core.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical Select DOES allow multiple vocabularies in drupal7. 1) Go to the given "HR Field" on your content type, 2) then select the "Widget Type" tab, 3) scroll down and configure the "Drop Box" settings. You'll see it. Also you might take a peek at this guys overview to see the skinny: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/05/29/drupal-7-mutiliple-selection-list-for-taxonomy-using-hierarchical-select/